# CCHmac with kCCHmacAlgSHA1 has inconsistent output length

Tags: objective-c, c, oauth, hmac

I'm working on an oauth library for iOS and about 10% to 15% of my requests are failing because the `oauth_signature` generated by my library is incorrect. I've traced the issue down to `CCHmac()` returning unexpected results. The signature fails when the hmac hash has an incorrect length. To verify this problem, I ran this code:

```
NSString *key = @"25f108b539761bd43b6c66b64fb191c8";

for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
    unsigned int chunks[4] = {
        arc4random() % ((int) pow(256, 4)),
        arc4random() % ((int) pow(256, 4)),
        arc4random() % ((int) pow(256, 4)),
        arc4random() % ((int) pow(256, 4))
    };

    // Generate a random input string of 32 hex chars
    NSString *input = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%08x%08x%08x%08x", chunks[0], chunks[1], chunks[2], chunks[3]];

    unsigned char output[CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];

    CCHmac(kCCHmacAlgSHA1, key.UTF8String, key.length, input.UTF8String, input.length, output);

    NSLog(@"HMAC Hash Length: %02lu", strlen(output));
}
```

... and got this output:

```
2013-12-06 16:05:24.596 ODB[98281:70b] HMAC Hash Length: 40
2013-12-06 16:05:24.596 ODB[98281:70b] HMAC Hash Length: 20
2013-12-06 16:05:24.596 ODB[98281:70b] HMAC Hash Length: 41
2013-12-06 16:05:24.596 ODB[98281:70b] HMAC Hash Length: 35
2013-12-06 16:05:24.596 ODB[98281:70b] HMAC Hash Length: 41
2013-12-06 16:05:24.597 ODB[98281:70b] HMAC Hash Length: 41
2013-12-06 16:05:24.597 ODB[98281:70b] HMAC Hash Length: 41
2013-12-06 16:05:24.597 ODB[98281:70b] HMAC Hash Length: 41
2013-12-06 16:05:24.597 ODB[98281:70b] HMAC Hash Length: 41
2013-12-06 16:05:24.597 ODB[98281:70b] HMAC Hash Length: 41
2013-12-06 16:05:24.597 ODB[98281:70b] HMAC Hash Length: 41
2013-12-06 16:05:24.597 ODB[98281:70b] HMAC Hash Length: 41
2013-12-06 16:05:24.598 ODB[98281:70b] HMAC Hash Length: 41
2013-12-06 16:05:24.598 ODB[98281:70b] HMAC Hash Length: 41
2013-12-06 16:05:24.598 ODB[98281:70b] HMAC Hash Length: 41
2013-12-06 16:05:24.598 ODB[98281:70b] HMAC Hash Length: 41
2013-12-06 16:05:24.795 ODB[98281:70b] HMAC Hash Length: 20
2013-12-06 16:05:24.795 ODB[98281:70b] HMAC Hash Length: 41
2013-12-06 16:05:24.795 ODB[98281:70b] HMAC Hash Length: 41
2013-12-06 16:05:24.795 ODB[98281:70b] HMAC Hash Length: 41
2013-12-06 16:05:24.796 ODB[98281:70b] HMAC Hash Length: 41
2013-12-06 16:05:24.796 ODB[98281:70b] HMAC Hash Length: 41
2013-12-06 16:05:24.796 ODB[98281:70b] HMAC Hash Length: 41
2013-12-06 16:05:24.796 ODB[98281:70b] HMAC Hash Length: 24
2013-12-06 16:05:24.797 ODB[98281:70b] HMAC Hash Length: 41
```

This method of hmac hashing seems to be pretty universally accepted so I would expect to see consistent output length. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, CCHmac outputs its result in binary form, so when this function finishes, output[] should always be filled with *exactly* 20 bytes.

Recall that strlen() just iterates through memory until it finds a 'null' byte, e.g.

```
int strlen(char *s)
{
  for(int n = 0; s[n] != 0; s++)
  {
    n++;
  }
  return n;
}
```

So, if it happens that one of the bytes in output[] is 0, then your NSLog statement will print out a value less than 20. Otherwise, strlen() will continue searching into undefined regions of memory until it happens to find a value of 0 somewhere. You will get largely unpredictable results, and this could actually make your program crash.

Instead, it looks like you may be expecting a hex-string representation of the HMAC. To get one, you could do something like:

```
NSMutableString *hexOutput = [NSMutableString string];
for (int i = 0; i < CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++) {
    [hexOutput appendFormat:@"%02x", output[i]];
}
```